React native with Android: Build fails
When I run npx react-native run-android I have an error that says:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\carlo\FitAI\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 420

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Command '[node, C:\Users\carlo\FitAI\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config, --platform, android]' failed with exit code 1.


When I navigated to the line 420 of native_modules.gradle, I couldn't find nothing, here is the code anyways

NATIVE_MODULES.GRADLE

Please find below the bin.js code too:
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

require("./tools/gracefulifyFs");
function _semver() {
  const data = _interopRequireDefault(require("semver"));
  _semver = function () {
    return data;
  };
  return data;
}
function _chalk() {
  const data = _interopRequireDefault(require("chalk"));
  _chalk = function () {
    return data;
  };
  return data;
}
function _cliDoctor() {
  const data = require("@react-native-community/cli-doctor");
  _cliDoctor = function () {
    return data;
  };
  return data;
}
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
if (_semver().default.satisfies(process.version, _cliDoctor().versionRanges.NODE_JS)) {
  const {
    run
  } = require('./');
  run();
} else {
  console.error(`${_chalk().default.red(`React Native needs Node.js ${_cliDoctor().versionRanges.NODE_JS}. You're currently on version ${process.version}. Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version and try again.`)}`);
}

//# sourceMappingURL=bin.ts.map

I tried cleaning my project by deleting node_modules and package_lock.json and then ran npm install again but it didn't work - the same with ./gradlew clean.
I hope you can help me, please, I don't know what to do
